# Evaluating a polynomial on one of its roots produces "a not so small" number

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, error-propagation

I am dealing with the roots of the following polynomial:

> $p(x) = 882x^{12} + 6867x^{11} + 23566x^{10} + 53265x^9 + 84904x^8 +
>  101863x^7 + 92002x^6 + 63175x^5 + 31576x^4 + 11089x^3 + 2302x^2 + 243x
>  + 10$

The matlab function `roots()` outputs:

```
 -3.333333333333349e+00 + 0.000000000000000e+00i
 -5.002524795857115e-01 + 8.661787610509997e-01i
 -5.002524795857115e-01 - 8.661787610509997e-01i
 -4.998466746602097e-01 + 8.662777735465724e-01i
 -4.998466746602097e-01 - 8.662777735465724e-01i
 -5.001532474054582e-01 + 8.657728922922465e-01i
 -5.001532474054582e-01 - 8.657728922922465e-01i
 -4.997475983486135e-01 + 8.658721882479348e-01i
 -4.997475983486135e-01 - 8.658721882479348e-01i
 -1.666666666666945e-01 + 0.000000000000000e+00i
 -1.428571428571326e-01 + 9.525799160446818e-09i
 -1.428571428571326e-01 - 9.525799160446818e-09i
```

So we have six (3 pairs of complex conjugate roots) which are very close to each other, two other complex roots and 2 real roots.  Now as far as I now problems can arise when the roots are very close to each other, what bothers me is the fact that evaluating the polynomial on all the roots using `polyval(p, roots(p))` outputs:

```
  2.407688793226726e-06 + 0.000000000000000e+00i
 -1.117346215551152e-10 - 1.041549069213943e-10i
 -1.117346215551152e-10 + 1.041549069213943e-10i
 -9.761613739556196e-11 - 1.169686569824080e-10i
 -9.761613739556196e-11 + 1.169686569824080e-10i
 -1.019273554447864e-10 - 1.033395591321096e-10i
 -1.019273554447864e-10 + 1.033395591321096e-10i
 -1.032542940038184e-10 - 1.166284846476628e-10i
 -1.032542940038184e-10 + 1.166284846476628e-10i
 -2.664535259100376e-14 + 0.000000000000000e+00i
 -3.552713678800501e-15 + 6.035109749186890e-21i
 -3.552713678800501e-15 - 6.035109749186890e-21i
```

Is this result normal? The polynomial evaluated on the first root results in ~$2.41 · 10^{-06}$

Could someone explain me this result? Should I trust the numerical aproximation of this first root?

Comment: It factors as $(3 x+10) (6 x+1) (7 x+1)^2 \left(x^2+x+1\right)^4$

Comment: You first root has magnitude $> 1$. Since your polynomial has relatively high order, a small error in root will be multiplied by a large derivative.  If we just keep the contribution from the leading term $882x^{12}$, the error in value will be error in root multiplied by a factor of order $882\times 12 \times (10/3)^{11} \approx 6\times 10^9$....

Comment: @achillehui  That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @Moo Thank you. As I see Matlab has actually failed by far, as it has not obtained the double root $1/7$.

Comment: Why does matlab "miss" the double root $1/7$? Because $1/7$ is not exactly representable as a floating point number, and it happens that for the floats just to the left and right of $1/7$, $(7x_L + 1)^2$ and $(7 x_R + 1)^2$ are both positive. There's no way for matlab to know whether there's a solution in there or not. In particular, there's no float $z$ for which $7z + 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the IEEE floating point specification. THat's what Matlab probably works with. Floats are not real numbers --- they're a very discrete sampling of the reals. When you get an answer like this one, there's a good chance that the number you get has the property that the floats on either side of it, $x_L$ and $x_R$, have the property that $p(x_L)$ and $p(x_R)$ have opposite signs, so there HAS to be a zero of the polynomial between them. (At least to the degree that you trust the floating point computation of $p$ at those points.) And that means that your particular "root" is one of the two floats that best approximate the root that must be in that interval.

Comment: Are you sure? That does not seem to be the way Matlab finds the roots of the polynomial. Also, following Moo's comment the root is actually correct up to 14 digits.

Comment: Matlab will find the correct root of $x(x^2+1) = 0$ up to infinitely many digits; that doesn't show whether it's using a particular algorithm or not. It's possible that it uses IEEE double- or quadruple-precision numbers, but it certainly uses SOME floating-point representation, and those all suffer from the same problem.